# How to use the MERN stack ( without errors )?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux, mern

I'm learning the MERN stack. I'm following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngc9gnGgUdA&t=941s

Basically when I run "npm start" it wont read my index.js. The tutorial Im following is fresh and highly rated.. but Im stuck at the very early of the tutorial, and the error message is not really implicit. Stuck after minute 15.

I would be grateful for some infos/guidance on this topic.

My steps till I started :

**mkdir server**

**cd server**

**npm init -y**

**npm install body-parser cors express mongoose nodemon**

**code package.json**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

**code index.js**

```
console.log('Why I cant read this file ?')

import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
```

**Now I run "npm start" and get the error**

```
[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
/home/pedrofromperu/next/32_testing_zone/memories_project/server/index.js:3
import express from 'express';
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The console log message dosnt even show ..

Comment: try deleting the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` to get a fresh install. I followed your steps and see the console.log without any issue.

Comment: thanks I tried, but the same error is still here .

Answer (score 0):

You are using nodemon so i think the command should be :                               **nodemon index**
Try this and let me know what happens

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).